# javascript class sees multiple DOMs in each iteration? jquery .each getting confused

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I have quite strange problem, I have simple quiz engine which should restart it self if user doesn't pass with 70% and more.

Everything works ok but when i re-init the script, in next iteration it seems like it sees all questin divs more times. (as many times as many times you failed) so it makes me a mess since every other calculation is based on that.

here is everything to see: http://jsfiddle.net/xdgrh/DhTQw/2/

You can replicate the issue if you choose B for the first question and anything else for other questions. Than it will tell you to click restart because you failed.

In next iteration again choose B and look in feedback. (i checked in log too, it reads everything like there is each question doubled.) And so on as many iterations you make, that many times it calculates everything

html here: (because it must be in post by stack rules)

**(Focus should be in $('.btnNext').click...  and in $(".box:visible input:radio").each(function(index, value)... there it counts things two-three.. more times.. depending on how may times you fail)**

```
<div id="lliquizContent">

<div id="headerX">
<h1>Task 1: Work with Today's Client (Final task) </h1>
</div>

<div class="feedback">
<div class="feedback-title">
FEEDBACK TITLE 
</div>
<div class="feedback-text">
FEEDBACK TEXT 
</div>
<img src="/Resource/GetResource/CRSTechModule1/feedback.m1s29.1.png" border="0" />
<div style="clear:both;"> </div>
<div class="feedback-footer">
<div class="btnFeedbackNext">Next Question ></div>
<div class="score"><strong>Score: &nbsp;&nbsp;</strong><span class="score"></span> %</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="box" type="1">
<div class="headerX">
<p>Task question 1 of 4</p>
</div>
<div class="question qsize1">
<div class="questionText">Based on Anne’s original email, how should you respond?</div>
<div class="answers">
<table>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td>
<td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td>
<td>
<feedback>
<fbtitle>Incorrect. You did not select the best approach for responding to Dr. Anne Jones. Click Next to view the next question.</fbtitle>
<fbtext>"I’d like to be able to meet with you, but as I said in my original email, I am just too busy! Please email me your thoughts about homes that might be suitable for my situation."</fbtext>
</feedback>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="" value="1" /> </td>
<td><label>Email Anne and ask her to register on your website.</label></td>
<td>
<feedback>
<fbtitle>Correct! You selected the best approach for responding to Dr. Anne Jones. Click Next to view the next question.</fbtitle>
<fbtext>"Thanks for getting back to me. I’ll look at the two homes you mentioned and try to register on your website when I get a chance. I am very excited about getting a new home in Springfield. Thanks for helping me."</fbtext>
</feedback>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td>
<td><label>Email Anne to qualify her as a possible lead.</label></td>
<td>
<feedback>
<fbtitle>Incorrect. You did not select the best approach for responding to Dr. Anne Jones. Click Next to view the next question.</fbtitle>
<fbtext>"I really don’t have any more information to give you at this time. As I wrote in my original email, I think new construction would be ideal for me. Can’t you just email me information on homes that are available? I don’t have a lot of time."</fbtext>
</feedback>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"> </div>

<div class="attachments">
<a id="transcript-button1" href="#" lliQuizTitle="Transcript 1 lliQuizTitle">Approach #1</a> | 
<div style="display: none;" id="TRANSCRIPT-TEXT1" lliQuizTitle="Transcript 1 lliQuizTitle">transcript 1</div> 
<a id="transcript-button2" href="#">Approach #2</a> | 
<div style="display: none;" id="TRANSCRIPT-TEXT2" lliQuizTitle="Transcript 2 lliQuizTitle">transcript 2</div>
<a id="transcript-button3" href="#">Approach #3</a>
<div style="display: none;" id="TRANSCRIPT-TEXT3" lliQuizTitle="Transcript 3 lliQuizTitle">transcript 3</div>
</div>

<div class="btnContainer"><a class="btnNext">SUBMIT</a></div>
<div class="instructions">Select the correct answer then click the forward arrow to continue.</div>

<div class="rightAttachmentBox">
<a id="transcript-button4" href="#">Click here</a><br />
to see the email from<br /> 
Anne Jones

<div style="display: none;" id="TRANSCRIPT-TEXT4" lliQuizTitle="Transcript 4 lliQuizTitle" lliQuizTop="20" lliQuizLeft="200" lliQuizWidth="300" lliQuizHeight="300">
    transcript 4 transcript 4 transcript 4
</div>

</div>
</div>

<div class="box" type="2">
<div class="headerX">
<p>Task question 2 of 4</p>
<div class="questionText">Based on Anne’s original email, how should you respond?</div>
</div>
<div class="questions qsize2">
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="question"> <div class="questionText">Based on Anne’s original email, how should you respond?</div> <div id="answers"> <table> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="1" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 1.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 2.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 3.</td> </tr> </table> </div> </div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="question"> <div class="questionText">Based on Anne’s original email, how should you respond?</div> <div id="answers"> <table> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="1" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 1.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 2.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 3.</td> </tr> </table> </div> </div>
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<div class="question"> <div class="questionText">Based on Anne’s original email, how should you respond?</div> <div id="answers"> <table> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="1" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 1.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 2.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 3.</td> </tr> </table> </div> </div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="question"> <div class="questionText">Based on Anne’s original email, how should you respond?</div> <div id="answers"> <table> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="1" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 1.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 2.</td> </tr> <tr> <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /> </td> <td><label>Email Anne to set up a face-to-face meeting.</label></td> <td id="fedback_content">Question response 3.</td> </tr> </table> </div> </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<feedback>
<correct>
<fbtitle>Correct...</fbtitle>
<fbtext>"Text..."</fbtext>
</correct>
<incorrect>
<fbtitle>Incorrect...</fbtitle>
<fbtext>"Text...."</fbtext>
</incorrect>
</feedback>

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
<div class="btnContainer"><a class="btnNext">SUBMIT</a></div>
<div class="instructions">Select the correct answer then click the forward arrow to continue.</div>
</div>

<div class="box qsize3" type="3">
<div class="headerX">
<p>Task question 3 of 4</p>
<p>Select the best Target group for you based on your data. Next, select your Rationale and click Submit to get your feedback. You may view your client analysis at any time to help you choose an approach.</p>
<div class="questionText">I’ve reviewed your client analysis and I have an idea of where you might be able to add a lot of value to your clients. But I want to know what you think.<br />
What target group do you think it makes the most sense for you to select? Why?</div>
</div>
<div class="questions qsize3">
<table>
<tr valign="top" >
<td>
<div class="question">
    <div class="questionText">Target group</div>
    <div id="answers">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /></td>
                <td><label> Doctors and nurses transferring to Springfield.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>I think you should focus on transfers into Springfield, however, I think that group may be a little too specific.</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /></td>
                <td><label>Home sellers with older homes looking to purchase new construction.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>I thought you didn’t like to work with this group.</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="0" />
                </td>
                <td><label>Home buyers looking for older homes outside of Springfield.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>I am not sure why you picked this group. I thought you liked new construction.</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" name="" value="1" />
                </td>
                <td><label>First-time home buyers and transfers to the area looking for new construction.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext></fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
</td>
<td>
<div class="question">
    <div class="questionText">Rationale</div>
    <div id="answers">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="" value="1" /></td>
                <td><label>I only want to focus on one specific group that is associated with the hospital.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>For the rest of this meeting, I think we should focus on first-time home buyers and transfers to the area looking for new construction.</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /></td>
                <td><label>I don’t want to pick between two of the buyer types with whom I enjoy working.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>For the rest of this meeting, I think we should focus on first-time home buyers and transfers to the area looking for new construction.</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /></td>
                <td><label>Older homes have a lot more character than new construction.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>For the rest of this meeting, I think we should focus on first-time home buyers and transfers to the area looking for new construction.</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="radio" name="" value="0" /></td>
                <td><label>Springfield is not expanding and there aren't new construction homes.</label></td>
                <td>
                    <feedback>
                        <fbtitle></fbtitle>
                        <fbtext>I agree that you should focus on first-time home buyers and transfers looking for new construction. But why did you select them?</fbtext>
                    </feedback>
                </td>
            </tr> 
        </table>
    </div> 
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>

<feedback>
<correct>
<fbtitle>Correct! You selected an appropriate target market and the best rationale. Click Next to view the next question.</fbtitle>
<fbtext>"I agree! I think you will be very happy working with this group and it sounds like you are well on your way to becoming a new construction expert. This expertise will add value to the service you provide your clients."</fbtext>
</correct>
<incorrect>
<fbtitle>You have a red X next to each incorrect answer. You did not select the best choices here. Click Next to view the next question.</fbtitle>
<fbtext></fbtext>
</incorrect>
</feedback>

<div style="clear: both;"> </div>
<div class="btnContainer"><a class="btnNext">SUBMIT</a></div>
<div class="instructions">Select the correct answer then click the forward arrow to continue.</div>
</div>

<div class="box-fail">
Ponovo init... <a href="#" id="initButton" onclick="">TRY AGAIN...MUST GET 70%+</a>
</div>

<div class="box-success">
It's on, go on...</div>
</div>
```

And here is s:

```
var lliQuiz = {
    message1: "message1",
    message2: "",
    feedbackImage: "/image/not/set",
    score: 0,
    currentTab: 0,
    checkFormat: function() {
        var $boxes = $('.box'), valid = $boxes.length > 0;
        if (valid) {$boxes.each(function (idx, box) {
                var $box = $(this),$qtns = $box.find('.question');
                if ($qtns.length == 0) {
                    valid = false; return false;
                } valid = $qtns.filter(function () {
                    return $(this).find('input[type="radio"]').length < 2;
                }).length == 0; if (!valid) { return; }
            })
        }
        if (valid) {return true;} else {return false;exit;}
    },
    createFeedback: function(boxVisible,type,farray,addScore) {
        $('.feedback img').attr('src',lliQuiz.feedbackImage);
        if (type == 1) {
            $.each(farray, function(i,id){ // NE TREBA FOR EACH??? samo je jedno pitanje...
                $('.feedback .feedback-title').text($('input[id='+id+']').nextInDOM('fbtitle').html());
                $('.feedback .feedback-text').text($('input[id='+id+']').nextInDOM('fbtext').html());
            });
        }
        if (type == 2) {
            if (addScore == true) {
              $('.feedback .feedback-title').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > correct > fbtitle').html());
              $('.feedback .feedback-text').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > correct > fbtext').html());
            } else {
              $('.feedback .feedback-title').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > incorrect > fbtitle').html());
              $('.feedback .feedback-text').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > incorrect > fbtext').html());
            }           
        }

        if (type == 3) {

            if (addScore == true) {
              $('.feedback .feedback-title').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > correct > fbtitle').html());
              $('.feedback .feedback-text').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > correct > fbtext').html());
            } else {
                var text = "";
                $.each(farray, function(i,id){
                    var br = (i == 0) ? "<br /><br />" : "";
                    text = text + " " + $('input[id='+id+']').nextInDOM('fbtext').html() + br;
                });
                $('.feedback .feedback-title').text($(boxVisible).find('feedback > incorrect > fbtitle').html());
                $('.feedback .feedback-text').html('"'+text+'"');
            }
        }
        return true; 
    },
    checkAnswers: function() { return 5; },
    init: function() {
        $('.box, .box-success, .box-fail').fadeOut(100);
        $('span.redx').remove();
        lliQuiz.score = 0;
        lliQuiz.currentTab = 0;
        console.log('init poeni: '+lliQuiz.score);

        // check format
        if (lliQuiz.checkFormat()) {
            $('.box:first').fadeIn(1000);
            console.log( "LLI - HTML FORMAT OK!!!" );
        } else {
            $('#lliquizContent').html('<div style="color: red; font-size: 16px; font-weight: bold; text-align: center; width: 100%;">HTML FORMAT ERROR</div>');
            console.log( "LLI - HTML FORMAT ERROR!!!" );
        }
        console.log( "LLI - Quiz Start!" );

        var pointsPerQuestion = parseFloat(100 / $('.box').length).toFixed(2);
        $(".question").each(function(index,value) {
            var groupNumber = ++index;
            $(":radio", this).attr("name", "group" + groupNumber).each(function(index,value){
                $(this).removeAttr('checked').attr("id","id"+groupNumber+index).nextInDOM('label').attr("for","id"+groupNumber+index);
            });
        });

        $('input').iCheck('uncheck'); 
        $('input').iCheck({ checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_minimal-blue', radioClass: 'iradio_flat-blue' });

        // lli idemo dalje...

        $('.btnNext').click(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var status = true;
                var addScore = false;
                var carray = []; carray.length = 0;
                var xarray = []; xarray.length = 0;
                var farray = []; farray.length = 0;
                lliQuiz.currentTab++;
                $('span.redx').remove();



                $(".box:visible input:radio").each(function(index, value){
                        if($("input:radio[name="+$(this).attr("name")+"]:checked").length == 0) {
                            status = false;
                        }
                        if(value.value == 1 && value.checked == true) {
                            carray.push($(this).attr("id"));
                            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                        }

                        if (value.value == 0 && value.checked == true)  {
                            xarray.push($(this).attr("id"));
                            console.log($(this).attr("id"));
                        }
                        if (value.checked == true)  {
                            farray.push($(this).attr("id"));
                            console.log($(this).attr("id")); 
                        }

                });

            if (carray.length == $(".box:visible .question").length) {

                lliQuiz.score += parseInt(pointsPerQuestion);
                    if (lliQuiz.score == 99) $('span.score').text(100);
                    else
                    $('span.score').text(lliQuiz.score);
                addScore = true;
            } else {
                addScore = false;
                if (lliQuiz.score == 0) $('span.score').text(0);
            }

            if (status == false) {
            $("#lliquizContent").block({ message: lliQuiz.message1 , theme: false, timeout: 2500, fadeOut: 400, overlayCSS: {opacity: 0.1, cursor: "default"}, css: {border: '1px solid #333',width: '200px', padding: '10px','border-radius': '7px', color: 'red', '-webkit-border-radius': '7px', '-moz-border-radius': '7px' } });
                exit;
            } else {
                $("#lliquizContent").block({ message: false , theme: false, overlayCSS: {opacity: 0.1, cursor: "default"} });

                $.each(xarray, function(i,id){
                    $('#'+id).prevInDOM('.questionText').prepend('<span class="redx">X</span>');
                });

                lliQuiz.createFeedback($(".box:visible"),$('.box:visible').attr('type'),farray,addScore);
                $(".feedback").fadeIn(1000);    
            }

        });

        $('.btnFeedbackNext').click(function() {
            console.log('feedback poeni: '+lliQuiz.score);
            if ($('.box').length == lliQuiz.currentTab) {
                $('.feedback').fadeOut(200);
                $('#lliquizContent').unblock();
                $('.box:visible').fadeOut(200);
                if (lliQuiz.score >= 70) {
                    $('.box:visible').fadeOut(300);
                    $('.box-success').fadeIn(1000);
                    $.hurdleNext(false);
                } else {
                    $('.box-fail').fadeIn(1000);
                    $.hurdleNext(true);
                }
            } else {
                $('.feedback').fadeOut(300);
                $('#lliquizContent').unblock();
                $('.box:visible').fadeOut(function(){
                    $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
                    return false;
                });
            }
        });
    },
    test: function() { alert('lli test'); }
}
    lliQuiz.message1 = "Please answer the questions before submiting!";
    lliQuiz.feedbackImage = "feedback.m1s29.1.png";
    lliQuiz.init();

    $('#initButton').click(function(){
        lliQuiz.score = 0;
        lliQuiz.init();
    });
```

Comment: Why someone gave "-1" to a question with out any comment???

Comment: You are re-adding click events every time you `.init()`

Comment: how can i get rid of that? how can i cancel that?? reset that??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you click `#initButton` you are adding another click event handler to your buttons.

Before you init, you should use `.unbind();` to clear the events.

```
$('#initButton').click(function(){

    // remove click handler for elements
    // use .unbind('click'); specifically to remove click events
    $('.btnFeedbackNext').unbind('click');
    $('.btnNext').unbind('click');

    lliQuiz.score = 0;
    lliQuiz.init();
});
```

**Edit:** In later versions of jQuery the preffered method is using `.off();`

Thanks to [@AnthonyGrist](https://stackoverflow.com/users/552438/anthony-grist) for pointing that out :)

Here is an example [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/dXpmV/)

Comment: In later versions of jQuery the preferred method is `.off()` rather than `.unbind()`. I suspect that `.unbind()` calls `.off()` anyway though.

Comment: please delete that fork if possible.

Comment: I removed it from my answer, but as far as deleting it, I don't think I can.